# HTML table cell padding insterted despite padding: 0

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm hacking Bootstrap table to achieve clickable rows. I feel like I'm very close to my goal, however I encountered a problem with cell padding.

Consider this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/64614/

```css
tr.table-href > td {
 padding: 0;
}

a.table-href {
 padding: 0.75rem;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Col 1</th>
          <th scope="col">Col 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Col 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Col 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-href">
          <td>
            <a class="table-href" href="#">Much much longer val than usual</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="table-href" href="#">Val 2</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="table-href" href="#">Some value 3</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="table-href" href="#">Some value 4</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>  
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm setting `td` padding to 0 so that the `a` inside can fill the content, thus making whole cell clickable. However, when some cells are too wide and get wrapped, shorter cells have some bottom padding inserted no matter what, even though Chrome dev tools tell me there's none:

[image]

Question: how do I get rid of this padding and make the `a` inside completely fill the cell table?

Comment: It's not padding. Is your question really, how to expand the `a` to be as high as its parent?

Comment: @MrLister I don't know what it is. It shows as padding, it acts as padding, so I'm using whatever naming I find applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
tr.table-href > td {
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

a.table-href {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

Setting the `td` to have a height will allow the `a` to usage a percentage height, but the `td` will still naturally grow when needed.

Comment: Right you are. Perhaps it's worth someone saying as an aside that styling like this doesn't seem that normal and probably isn't good UI to have clickable links extend into whitespace like this.

Comment: @Coop I find the use case to be completely justified. You have tabular data, so table is a natural display layout, and each row corresponds to a page so you want to make it clickable. If `a` doesn't fill the entire height, parts of the row won't be clickable. Is there any other way to get around it, UI-wise?

Comment: @Red If you want an entire row to be a link then I'd maybe do just that. Ditch the table and have a single link for each row with nested spans, rather than multiple links to the same source and styling issues. This would likely result in less markup, more machine readable code and better SEO.